# Java Script + Node.js Calculator issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, calculator

I am a "new" developer into the foray of Web Development and I have come across an issue I was hoping that you fine people on Stack Overflow would be able to help me with. I have asked several Cadre and Instructors in my class and we are all stumped by it.

To start with I have decided to put all of my code on a Gitlab repo so if you want to look at the whole thing (or if you want to add to it let me know): [Link to Github Repo](https://github.com/KodyShaw/Calculator). I fiqured you guys don't want the whole thing posted as a wall of text and rather some snip-its of what in the file I specifically. But it is relitively small file

I am useing simple JavaScript as well as Node.Js to be able to build a working calculator in the back end that I can use as a template for any other project I will need to work on in the future. For now I am trying to just get it working by imputing things via the console.

I have made a way for what is imputed in Node and to an imputArray var I have set up and the Array goes something like this:

```
 [(command), (num1), (num2), (num3), ...]
```

I set up a switch function that runs a block of code based on what command was given (add, subtract, divide, etc..). As well as separating the command from the number and putting them inside another array.

The part I need some help with is with getting the block of code to work for what I want it to do. I have got it set up to run rather easily on two numbers but I want it to handle as many numbers as I want to throw at it. I tried various forms of for loops as well as forEach loops and I cant seem to get it working.

```
 case 'divide':

    for (i = 1; i < numArray.length; i++) { // If any number besides the first is 0 spit out this
        if (numArray[i] === 0) {
            consol.log("You canot divide by zero!");
        }
        else {
            var previousTotal = numArray[0]; //Inital number in array       

            for (i = 1; i < numArray.length; i++) {
                previousTotal = previousTotal / numArray[i]; // for each number in array divide to the previous number
            }
        }

        result = previousTotal // Pushes end total to result
    }

    break;
```

I have gone through several different versions of the above code (such as using for loops instead) but this is pretty much what I ended up with. I'm sure there is an easier way and more sane way to do what I am trying to do, but if I knew how I wouldn't be here.

Essentially this is the ideal thing I want to do but I cant find a way to do it: I want to run a small block of code the index of the number array, minus one. In this case it is dividing the previous number by the next number in the array.

So it only runs if there are more then one in the array and it does the function to the previous number, or total from the last one in the array.

This is pretty much the only thing holding me back from finishing this so if someone can take the time to look at my crapy code and help it do what I want it to do that would be awesome.

Comment: shouldn't you use a different variable instead of i for the inner loop?

Comment: @AlexG yes that is an easy fix and since has been fixed.  Initially the for loop above and the one above are the same thing. But for what ever strange reason (probably some scoping nonsense) the "i" var doesn't work as intended below it. My quick solution was to just copy paste it again below and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is reseting result each time the outer loop iterates so it will just equal what ever the last prev Total is. Basically every loop but the last is irrelevant. Do you want to add them to result? If so you want:

```
result += previousTotal
```

Or if you want an array of the answers you want:

```
result.push(reviousTotal)
```

Sorry not 100% what you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: that actually worked.... i haven't tested it to the extreme yet but.... i cant believe that helped.

Comment: Don't worry too much. Some of the hardest stuff to fix is this sort of thing. I've spent two days trying to debug to find that two lines where the wrong way round!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the divide command to do `((num1/num2)/num3)/...`

There are couple of issues in the code you posted, I will post a version that does the above. You can inspect and compare it your version to find your mistakes.

```
  // divide, 10, 2, 5
 case 'divide':
    if (numArray.length < 2) {
        console.log("no numbers in array")
        break;
    }
    // previousTotal starts with 10
    var previousTotal = numArray[1]; 

    // start from the second number which is 2
    for (i = 2; i < numArray.length; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] === 0) {
            console.log("You canot divide by zero!");
        }
        else {
            previousTotal = previousTotal / numArray[i]; // for each number in array divide to the previous number
        }
    }
    result = previousTotal;
    // result will be (10/2)/5 = 1
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried your version of code. I have tried other numbers other then what you had and the expected result was different from what i received. For example i used (12/2)/2) which should give me 3. However i still get only 1 as an answer. But i will take your structure of your code over mine as mine is madness.

Comment: I have combined your code structure with Edward's suggestion above... it seemed to have worked. I cant believe that is was as simple as a +=.

Answer (score 0):

You just need one loop, and you probably want to stop iterating if a 0 occurs:

```
 result = numArray[0]; //no need for another variable

 for (var i = 1; i < numArray.length; i++) { // declare variables!
   if (numArray[i] === 0) {
     console.log("You canot divide by zero!"); // typo...
     break; // exit early
   }       
   result = result / numArray[i];            
 }
```

For sure that can be also written a bit more elegantly:

```
 const result = numArray.reduce((a, b) => a / b);
 if(isNaN(result)) {
   console.log("Can't divide by zero!");
 } else {
   console.log(`Result is ${result}`);
 }
```

Comment: Interesting... can you break down what is going on in your second block of code? there are a few ideas in there that i am not used to as a programmer yet.

Comment: @kody `reduce` can be used to turn an array into one single value, in this case by dividing the previous result by the current element, and that goes on so the first gets divided by the second, the result of that by the third, the result of that by the fourth and so on. If You try to divide by zero, the result will be NaN (not a number) so you can easily check for that at the end of the loop.

Comment: interesting.... Hmm I will definitely take a look a look at it. It is definitely a simpler way to do it... just not a way i am used to yet.